# C# Desktop Application

Tags: winforms, desktop-application, local-database

I built a desktop application using local database mdf and ldf file. When I test my application via complete installation process in other machine which has no SQL management software installed. I am getting an  error 52. I see that after installation local mdf and ldf files was created but my application unable to access them. I want my application to run on any window based machine. Did I configure my connection string wrong or did I miss something during creating a set up file?
My connection string is:

`Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;`

Can someone help me to configure my application to run on other machines?